# How to protect the database connection details from Resource Hacker?

Tags: delphi

My application is written using : Embarcadero Delphi 2010

I have a form named INCLUDEFORM which i included in all other forms, this form contain, TSQLQuery and TSQLConnection which contain the database connection details ( db host, db name, db user, and db pass ) which are defined in the design time.

Yesterday, i installed a software named ( Resource Hacker ), i tried to open my application using this software, and when i was looking for resources i have seen all forms in my application including the includeform, i clicked in the include form to see the code source, and i saw all the code source and daabase connection details.

I tried to open other similar applications to mine using the resource hacker, but i didn't see any important details, only Icon, Icon group, and Version Info.

Please, is it possible to encrypt my source code from Resource Hacke, or at least the code in the INCLUDE FORM which contain the important database connection details.

Thankyou

Comment: you should not store your connection string in the form. the least you can do is define a constant or variable and assign it to your DB connection string components at run-time (it can also be encrypted).

Comment: You must assume that any decently competent attacker can extract the db connection from the client, and secure the server accordingly. I'd just use ethereal if you use an unencrypted connection to the server, and a hook on your encryption function(Probably SSL library) if you do. No client side obfuscation will protect you from that.

Comment: Dont struggle, release under GPL.

Comment: @user539484: The GPL doesn't cover things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the connection string at form creation time, in-code and obfuscate/encrypt the string that is being used, rather than leaving it in at design time. Generally, I don't use a connection to the live database in my development, but a connection to a test database that is typically more access restricted than the production database e.g. behind a firewall, inside a NAT gateway.

Simple obfuscation mechanisms include performing an XOR of the string. More complex methods, like encryption, require the addition of libraries to perform the encryption/decryption.

If you're just trying to protect the connection string, these methods are simple to accomplish. If you're trying to accomplish full obfuscation/encryption of the form data, then using packers like UPX is the simplest mechanism, but is, again, trivial to work around.

Overall, anything you do will probably only delay the obtaining of the connection string for the database - this is due to the nature of software based protections - because you have everything that is needed to perform the connection, it is only a matter of time and effort before the information will be revealed.

If you truly want to protect the connection to the database, then you need to have a username/password combination for each user, and require this data to be input at execution time

Answer (score 5):

You should never store connection details inside the application, especially since they may (and password should) change. You can:

- If your database allows for it, use operating system authentication, the database client will use the process user security token to authenticate against the database. Oracle, SQL Server and other have such functionality
- Ask the informations when the user connects. If you store your user/password inside the executable, it's as having no user/password at all. For the matter, you could set your database with a known user and no password and the level of security is the same.
- Store those informations somewhere, in an encrypted form. Of course now you have to safely store the encryption key. You can use Windows encryption facilities (which could encrypt/decrypt data using the user or machine account), or you (or your user) have to store that key properly.

Comment: +1 - in addition to these comments, you can also create a service that authenticates the clients via standard auth mechanisms (basic/ssl, etc...) and the service stores the DB info.

Comment: @bryanmac: you're just moving the issue to another place. People having access to the machine which is running the service might not have access to the database, and you may need to protect form internal threats also. Morever this way each user would use the service credentials (and permissions), and that is not always what you need, you may want each user logged in with its own account for security and auditing reasons. You may recode security and auditing inside the application, but IMHO is a dangerous approach, especially when more than one application may need to access the same data.

Comment: @idsandon - no - it saves you from having to create logins and manage permissions at the database server level.  All web servers have standard/proven mechanisms for auth (basic+ssl, ntlm, oath etc...) which gives you the identity which you can implement authorization in your app.  That allows you to change your storage & identity store while maintaining a public protocol to your app.  The service maintains the DB creds as a config setting which is not exposed.  Standard SaaS arch.

Comment: @bryanmac: bypassing DB security is often the wrong choice. When you have access rule in place at the DB level, you don't have to recode them in each application accessin your data. Security is a kind of constraint. You can get rid of db constraints and implement it at the application level, but it's always riskier. Moreover policies and laws may require audting on data access. Again, implementing it at the database level make it harder to bypass. Anyway service settings are exposed to those managing the services. Often those people should not access the data. Database are not storage only.

Comment: No one is suggesting DB security is bypassed.  In most services, different roles are created in the DB granting different levels of permissions.  The application tier/web service stores the db credentials used and the different areas of code use that.  Having a two tier (client to DB) has many other downsides (including non-pooled connections).  As soon as you get to a three tier/SaaS approach you get into the arch I'm describing.  Its standard (even in highly secured govt used services) to auth @ the service and have the service auth to the DB.

Comment: @bryanmac: it's standard just because many n-tier applications are badly designed (as those implementing constraints client-side) and database features overlooked trying to find the holy grail of "database indipendence" (why not language/framework indepencende, then?).Oracle for example introduced "proxy users" exactly for the reason of having a middle-tier user that can impersonate a "client-tier" user and the database will apply the proper privileges. Do your service logs to the operating system all with "SYSTEM" privileges? If so you have another issue.

Comment: No the service runs with least privileges both in accessing the os and db resources.  Typically a service acct that is explicitly granted privileges to the minimal resources it needs

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cheapest way is [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/), but it's also the easiest to hack. This will, however, make all your resources invisible to a casual looker.

Having said that, there are ready-made unpackers for most products that are actually intended for hacker protection too, so you need to consider how much money you're willing to spend vs. the level of protection you get.

Comment: Thankyou, just another one question: i compressed my application using UPX, can i make the appliation more and more defficault to unpack using another compressor.  ( compress the application 2 or three times with different compressors ? )

Comment: Nothing like that will make you app any harder to crack. UPX will leave you app trivially easy to crack and will make it liable to be detected by virus scanners. Packing the entire .exe is gross overkill if what you really want to do is encrypt a couple of strings in the app. If what you want to do is encrypt a string in your app then encrypt a string.

Comment: Downvoted because even non-programmers can un-upx something just by using universal extractor or Pe.explorer and then the problem is still there

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's because I confused your comment with the next commenter's "Downvoted because". Sorry :)